# Allow JSF input text to be selected at first pass, cursor position

Tags: input, jsf-2, textinput

We are seeing odd behavior with JSF inputs that we dont see on regular html input fields.

The field is a search box, and **users will commonly swipe the mouse across the field to highlight all existing text, and start overtyping.**

You can try this on Google to see what i mean (type a search, leave the field, now clickin on the right side of your entry drag the mouse left - voila, all text is highlighted.)

If **we try this exact same process in our JSF app, the cursor just jumps to index 0,** and no text is highlighted. Users must repeat the stpe without leaving the field for it to actually highlight the text.

So my question is **a**) why the difference **b**) how to work around it

JSF 2.0 (MOjarra)

```
<h:inputText 
class="requiredFields" 
id="Search_String" 
value="#{searchManager.searchString}" 
maxlength="#{searchManager.searchTypeMaxLength()}" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was the result of a hacky implementation of some jQuery validation. Once the faulty library was removed the text box behaves like a text box should!